# Which Coefficient will Make a 2-Variable Linear System Solvable?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

This is most likely a pretty simple problem although my textbook doesn't quite explain how to solve it. I have a linear system with two equations and two variables (x and y) below:

```
2x - 5y = 9

4x + ay = 5 ('a' being the unknown coefficient of y)
```

The question asks to find the value of `a` that will make this system have a single solution. At first this seemed trivial, although I tried 1) multiplying the top equation by -2 and then adding the two equations to eliminate x. I then got stuck at 10y + ay = -4. And 2) I tried only multiplying the top by 2 to get the 4x terms in both equations, in which case I thought that I could somehow remove the x terms out of both equations entirely but I don't think that's correct (unless I do it to both sides which doesn't help me much?). Thanks in advance for any help!

I also wasn't able to think of any suitable tags for this question except "systems of equations" (which is supposed to be used on conjunction with a more specific tag). Couldn't find "linear equations" or other more suited tags.

Comment: Both your methods work, by the way. In your second attempt, after multiplying by $2$, you then have to *subtract* one equation from the other to get rid of the $x$, rather than adding. This effectively amounts to the same thing as multiplying by $-2$ and adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. One small mistake so far: you forgot to multiply the $9$ in the first equation by $-2$, so you should end up with $10y+ay=-13$. Now, if there were a unique solution, then we would be able to solve for $y$, thus:
$$y(10+a) = -13\\
y = \frac{-13}{10+a}$$

What does that say about restrictions on $a$? (You should be able to see that there is one forbidden value. As an experiment, try letting $a$ equal that value, then graph both equations.)

Comment: Ah, thanks! So the coefficient a can be anything but -10? So there is no way to find a unique solution for this system? Ah cool, just graphed them, a value of -10 for will make the slopes of the lines equal so there is no solution, anything else results in a unique solution.

Comment: @MagnusQ.: Good work! The restriction is that $a \neq -10$. But for any other value of $a$, you can find a unique solution, because you have $y=\frac{-13}{10+a}$, and from there you can find $x$ using either of the initial equations.

Comment: @MagnusQ.: Try, for example, setting $a=3$ (this will make the fraction cancel out nicely) and solving algebraically for $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that would keep the system from yielding a single value is if $2a+20=0$ or $a=-10$. In that case the loci of the two equations would be parallel. No intersections means no solutions.